# How to add list of items to Blazor Components as markup rather than an attribute

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm looking to create a Blazor Component that is used like this:

**TestPage.razor**

```
<MyCustomComponent @bind-Value=MyItem>
    <Items>
      <Item Key="blah" Value="Something" />
    </Items>
</MyCustomComponent>
```

In the custom component, I then want to iterate through "Items".

**MyCustomComponent.razor**

```
@foreach(var item in Items)
{
   if (item.Key == somevalue)
   {
       ... Insert Markup here.
   }
}
```

I would prefer not to use an attribute on MyCustomComponent.  I want it to work like an InputSelect works where you bind to your model but you can define the options for the select as ""

Comment: Ok, I have a working example of how to do this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77349496/custom-blazor-component-collection-is-being-reset-before-rendering