# Custom Blazor Component Collection is being reset before Rendering

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

SOLVED! I made a few dumb errors in creating this example when I was trying to track down my real issue.  I've edited the code to give a working example.

I've created a component that is similar to a grid but specific to my needs.  The problem that I am running into is that my Collection of property names are being reset when it's time to render the components.

The idea is that this will display a grid of properties for the object in the Item attribute.  You can define which properties are displayed and what their Title is.

Here is the code:

**Home.razor**

```cs
@page "/"
@attribute [RenderModeInteractiveServer]
@using BlazorApp1.Components.CustomComponents

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<div class="container">
    <PropertyList Item="Blah">
        <PropertyListItem Title="First Name" PropertyName="FirstName"></PropertyListItem>
        <PropertyListItem Title="Last Name" PropertyName="LastName"></PropertyListItem>
        <PropertyListItem Title="Bool Value" PropertyName="BoolValue"></PropertyListItem>
        <PropertyListItem Title="Int Value" PropertyName="IntValue"></PropertyListItem>
    </PropertyList>
</div>

@code {

    private TestClass? Blah= null;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Blah = new();
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        string TestProperty { get; set; } = "Test";
        string FirstName { get; set; } = "John";
        string LastName { get; set; } = "Doe";
        bool BoolValue { get; set; } = true;
        int IntValue { get; set; } = 123;
        string IngoreMe { get; set; } = "Ignore Me";
    }
}
```

**PropertyListItem.razor**

```
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? Title { get; set; } = "";

    [Parameter]
    public string? PropertyName { get; set; } = "";

    [Parameter]
    public bool HideIfEmpty { get; set; } = true;

    [Parameter]
    public bool Visible { get; set; } = true;

    [CascadingParameter]
    private PropertyList? Parent { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (Parent == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Parent), "List Item must exist within a Property List Control");
        }

        Parent.AddProperty(this);

        base.OnInitialized();
    }
}
```

**PropertyList.razor**

In this code, the AddProperty is called once for each property defined and it's saved in the ListOfProperties collection.  However when it gets to the code here:

```
        foreach (var propertyItem in ListOfProperties)
```

ListOfProperties is empty.

```
<CascadingValue Value="this">
    @ChildContent
</CascadingValue>

@if (Item is not null && ListOfProperties is not null)
{
    string rowCss = "";
    string itemValue = "";
    int rowCount = 0;

    foreach (var propertyItem in ListOfProperties)
    {
        if (propertyItem.Visible == false || string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyItem.Title))
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (propertyItem.HideIfEmpty)
        {
            itemValue = GetPropertyValue(Item, propertyItem.PropertyName!);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemValue))
            {
                continue;
            }
        }

        rowCount++;
        if (rowCount % 2 == 0)
        {
            rowCss = @EvenRowCss;
        }
        else
        {
            rowCss = @OddRowCss;
        }

        <div class="row @rowCss">
            <div class="col-6">
                @propertyItem.Title
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                @GetPropertyValue(Item, propertyItem.PropertyName!)
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
else
{
    @EmptyListText
}


@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public object? Item { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string EmptyListText { get; set; } = "No items to display";

    [Parameter]
    public string? LabelCss { get; set; } = "fw-bolder";

    [Parameter]
    public int LabelWidth { get; set; } = 4;

    [Parameter]
    public string? ValueCss { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public int ValueWidth { get; set; } = 8;

    [Parameter]
    public string EvenRowCss { get; set; } = "bg-light";

    [Parameter]
    public string OddRowCss { get; set; } = "";

    private List<PropertyListItem> ListOfProperties = new();

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        }

        base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
    }

    internal void AddProperty(PropertyListItem p_item)
    {
        ListOfProperties.Add(p_item);
    }

    private string ConvertBoolToText(bool p_value, string p_trueString, string p_falseString)
    {
        if (p_value)
        {
            return p_trueString;
        }
        else
        {
            return p_falseString;
        }
    }

    private string GetPropertyValue(object p_item, string p_propertyName)
    {
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags bf;

        if (p_item is null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(p_propertyName))
        {
            return "";
        }

        bf = System.Reflection.BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic;

        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo? property = p_item.GetType().GetProperty(p_propertyName, bf);

        if (property is null)
        {
            return "";
        }

        var value = property.GetValue(p_item);

        if (value is null)
        {
            return "";
        }

        return value.ToString() ?? "";
    }

}
```

Comment: A small criticism: there's an awful lot to read here. Consider trimming code down before posting, for instance w/o all the CSS logic.

Comment: I did trim it down and I wanted to post a complete example so that others might try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need two renders. Add this to PropertyList:

```cs
protected override void OnAfterRender(bool first)
{
   if (first) StateHasChanged();
}
```

From the docs:

> A parent component renders before its children components because rendering is what determines which children are present.

Comment: Thank you, this resolved this issue and the other one I was trying to reproduce!  I appreciate the help!